# Google Spreadsheet: Conditional format used together with a range doesn't seem to format cells correctly

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-cell-format

I'm trying to create a small calendar, which is built like this:

```
A1: = DATE(2018, 1, 1);

B4: = A1
C4: = A1 + 1
D4: = A1 + 2
…
```

This works fine and the columns B2 … D4 looks ok:

```
Mon, 01/01 | Tue, 02/01 | Wed, 03/01
```

Now I want to fill all weekends and their following rows gray, like:

```
Fri, 05/01 (F4, white) | Sat, 06/01 (G4, gray)
white                  | gray
white                  | gray
white                  | gray
```

I come up with this formula:

```
=OR(WEEKDAY(F4)=1,WEEKDAY(F4)=7)
```

which works fine for one cell. Now I wanted to apply this to the whole column, like:

```
Apply to range: F4:F25
Apply to range: G4:G25
```

But, this is what it looks like now:

```
Fri, 05/01 (F4, white) | Sat, 06/01 (G4, gray)
gray                   | gray
gray                   | gray
gray                   | gray
```

Why isn't this working as expected? Do I need to create a custom format for every single cell? That would be a huge letdown, especially, when copying a cell with conditional formatting, this cell is simply added to the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to lock it down with **`$`** symbol otherwise it will be offset (like in your case) or not working as it should.

the custom formula you are looking for is: **`=OR(WEEKDAY(B$4)=1, WEEKDAY(B$4)=7)`** applied to **`B4:I25`**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot - I just came home and was preparing an example file for your. :D This works perfectly. I didn't know about the `$` operator. That's pretty neat. Thank you very much.